# Fill custom termset in People group by userprofile

Tags: 2013, user-profile, term-set

If you go to the managed metadata service, there is a group called "People". This is a standard SharePoint 2013 group and contains some default termsets ("Department", "Job title", "Location"). As I read somewhere else, these terms are filled by the userprofile of the users.

How can I extend this "People" group to other properties from my userprofile so that it get's automatically filled and updated from the userprofiles?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the userprofile properties and edit a property, there is an option:

"Configure a Term Set to be used for this property". Check this and it should work.